# Snakemake merge multiples bam files using bamtools

Tags: yaml, snakemake

I have several BAM files in different directories that I want to merge. In my config.yaml file I indicate the paths to the files I want to merge:

```
var:
   var1: [ "/DATA/utent3/DATI/var/var1/leaf/trimmed/leaf_var1_ref1.bam", "/DATA/utent3/DATI/var/var1/stem/trimmed/stem_var1_ref1.bam", "/DATA/utent3/DATI/var/var1/flower/trimmed/flower_var1_ref1.bam" ]
....
   var9: [ "/DATA/utent3/DATI/var/var9/leaf/trimmed/leaf_var9_ref1.bam", "/DATA/utent3/DATI/var/var9/stem/trimmed/stem_var9_ref1.bam", "/DATA/utent3/DATI/var/var9/flower/trimmed/flower_var9_ref1.bam" ]

executables:
    bamtools: /home/utent3/anaconda3/bin/bamtools
```

And this is my snakefile

```
configfile: "config.yaml"
workdir: "/DATA/utent3/DATI/var/"

rule all:
    input:
        expand("{sample}.accepted.bam", sample = config["var"])

rule bamtools:
    input:
        bams = lambda wildcards: config["var"][wildcards.sample]
    output:
        bam = "{sample}.accepted.bam"
    params:
        executable = config["executables"]["bamtools"]
    run:
        shell("{params.executable} merge -list {input.bams} -out {output.bam}")
```

I get this error:

```
WorkflowError: Target rules may not contain wildcards. Please specify concrete files or a rule without wildcards.
```

**In general could someone explain how to write in config file multiple file paths.**

**UPDATE**
Now it says (for now I am trying only with var1):

```
ERROR: Some problems were encountered when parsing the command line options:
   An unrecognized argument was found: /DATA/utent3/DATI/var/var1/stem/trimmed/stem_var1_ref1.bam
   An unrecognized argument was found: /DATA/utent3/DATI/var/var1/flower/trimmed/flower_var1_ref1.bam
```

I think it is because it is not reading the config.file var correctly...

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you are executing snakemake as

```
snakemake [opts] bamtools
```

instead of just

```
snakemake [opts]
```

With the former command you are making "bamtools" the target rule which, as the error says, contains wildcards.

Comment: sorry, there was a line missing in the code with params: executable

Answer (score 0):

So, according to bamtools help merge documentation, I solved the problem adjusting the following part of the script, for sure not the best way, but works:

```
run:
    shell("{params.executable} merge -in {input.bams[0]} -in {input.bams[1]} -in {input.bams[2]} -out {output.bam}")
```

Comment: Note that if you're not running any Python code, you may as well drop the `run:` directive and simplify to `shell: "..."`